# Format URL query string (like Stack Overflow) with Laravel 5

Tags: php, string, url, laravel, get

In my web application I'd like to have URLs to posts, exactly like here in Stack Overflow. For example:

http://mydomain/posts/214741/this-is-the-postname

However when I write a route like:

```
Route::get('post/{postid}/{postname}',array('as' => 'postlink', 'uses' => 'Post@singlePost'));
```

What happens right now is the following:

1) Paste this link in address bar:

```
http://mydomain/en/post/214741/postname
```

2) Press enter, and due to the get request the link becomes:

```
http://mydomain/en/post/214741/postname?q=post%2F214741%2Fpostname
```

However, what I want is that the URL stays exactly the same as when I pasted it, exactly how it happens when you paste a Stack Overflow link in your browser and click Enter.

I need it to be a get request because users can use the link directly and therefore my controller needs to get the information directly from it.

What would be the best way to deal with this situation with Laravel?

My `.htaccess` file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your asking how to pass the {postid} and {postname} to the Post controllers singlePost() method?

Comment: "since it's a get request a query string will show up in the link" - what query string is showing up? Not `postid` or `postname`, surely? Do you mean as a result of submitting a `get` form?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like the link to be formated like I said

Comment: In what circumstances does the browser point to a link of that kind? Is this from a form submission?

Comment: @halfer I added some more stuff to my original post. The browser points to this link when I paste the url in the browser and press enter

Comment: Is it just the one route thats effected? If it's all routes then it sounds like it could be some kind of mod_rewrite issue. Whats your .htaccess look like?

Comment: your rewritebase is set to `/public`, this doesn't match up with your urls. Is the public folder not set as the webroot for the domain?

Comment: @Jeemusu And yes all get routes have the query strings like I showed in OP. It didn't really matter for the other pages but for this one it does

Comment: @Jessmusu I don't think so, my URL's do not have /public , I'm not really sure why that's on the htaccess file

Comment: @Mr.Phil The problem is right there in your htaccess. You need to remove the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1` line, and replace it with the original thats commented out. You should also remove the `rewritebase` line as thats probably not helping. Why did you change the original htaccess?

Comment: @Jeemusu I didn't, maybe someone else did though. Thanks for your input I'll try to find out why it was changed and try what you suggested. +1 for trying to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86656/discussion-between-mr-phil-and-jeemusu).

Comment: @halfer Sure, I'll edit my post right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` looks as though it has been changed to pass the requested uri back into the index.php as a query string variable of a parameter `q`.

Instead of this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1
```

Try changing it back to the original that came with Laravel.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the link now looks like:

http://mydomain/en/index.php/post/214741/postname . Is there any way to remove the "index.php" from the URL's ?

Comment: How are you handling the `/en/` uri's? I would expect my url to be more like `http://mydomain/index.php/en/post/214741/postname`. Is the `en` directory your webroot for the virtual host?

Comment: Yes I typed the link manually in that comment, you're right /en/ comes after index.php. Thing is I don't want "index.php" to appear in the link at all. Thanks

Comment: Even the /en/ part should be removed, if possible

Comment: I would recommend posting a new question. Include your .htaccess (people will ask), and your routes, indicate which directory your webroot is.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could add a pattern for postName variable

```
Route::get('/{postId}/{postName}', function($postId, $postName) {
  return "$postId - $postName";
})->where('postName', '.*');
```

Is your problem happening on production or on Laravel's dev server?

Comment: Looks like I had a problem in my htaccess file and it's solved now. Thanks for your input though

Comment: It was happening on dev server btw